# Print message after finished of every task

Tags: php

I know the title of subject not clear, but I will explain what the intended of that title.

Firstly
I have a form contain some fields, and submit button.
That form will make a request to another page `upgrade2.php` like:

```
<form action="upgrade2.php" method="post">
  <input ......>
  <input ......>
  <input type="submit" name="open_upgrade2" value="ok" />
</form>
```

Now, the page `upgrade2.php` has more than task like the following:

```
<?php
  task 1
  task 2
  task 3
?>
```

What I want is after end of every task print message like:

```
<?php
  task 1
  echo task 1 finished
  task 2
  echo task 2 finished
  task 3
  echo task 3 finished
?>
```

I'm tried use `sleep` ,`ob_flush` and `flush` functions to stop execution some time to print message and then continue execution, but unfortunately, the script must execute all taskst in same time and then tell me the result, but this is not what I want.

I want print message after end of every task.

Comment: You would have to split the tasks and call each task by ajax, I guess that would be the best solution

Comment: What do you need the print finished messages for? If the script is going to automatically continue anyway, not seeing the messages until it's done shouldn't be a problem. They'll be temporally-ordered when you finally get them whenever the script flushes the buffer, so if that's your issue, you just need to wait for the script to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do some things:

1) turn off ob_caching (or add ob_flush after every task/output)

2) use [flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) after each task/output or deactivate buffer

3) ensure that the webserver doesn't cache/wait/buffering until script is finished.
this depends on modul/cgi/webserver. i think here is your problem.

try you program on cli first and check output.
then run it thru the webserver.
which webserver are you using and how does it use/call/execute php?

Comment: I'm using after every task `ob_end_flush()` and `flush()`. now work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not that long ago, I did something similar, but used a bit of a work around for the displaying.

Rather than depending on php flush capabilities, I used AJAX like calls to retrieve the status, which was stored in memcache.

I made one file for the ajax request, which would simply return the memcache value for the currently logged in user, which was an array with the tasks, and their finished state (true or false).
And depending on that result the javascript would alter the HTML.

For the process script its simply editing the memcache value every time a task is finished.

It seems to be a lot of work, but its implementable well within an hour, and you have way more control over the outputted HTML.

Comment: in this php file, I don't use javascript, and I don't need to use javascript.